# Higher CPU usage when more programs using the CPU

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage

I'm not entirely sure how to phrase the question, but it's not just that the other programs are taking up cpu usage.
This is what my cpu usage looks like, and I thought "prime95 uses around 50% of the cpu, so I should be able to run it and still be at 75%"
[image: task manager screenshot 1]
But then I run prime95, and the cpu usage of all the other programs go up as well
[image: task manager screenshot 2]
does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: By default, Prime95 uses all CPU cores. Also, “Warframe Launcher” is clearly doing some different work in the second screenshot. If you want to measure whatever you’re going to measure, close all programs whose behavior you cannot control.

Comment: (i think) my prime95 is set to use half of them, and it usually takes up around very close to 50%. as well, this (warframe launcher using more cpu) has happened every time i started recently prime95, which is what prompted me to post this question. i've tested it a few more times to make sure, and warframe only uses more cpu when prime95 is started

Comment: There are common components that are shared by all cores, such as the RAM. When one program is executing at full-speed, it does disturb the others.